# combine duplicate rows in apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Current sheet

[image: Current]

Required sheet

[image: Required]

I have an addon that combines duplicate rows, but I want apps script to run onEdit trigger.

Comment: which cell or cells should onEdit be triggered from?

Comment: I want apps script to combine duplicate rows and this script will run on the onEdit trigger.

Comment: onEdit() trigger fires and starts a script when a user enters a value into a cell. Can you provide an use case - in which cell, what value you would enter to run the script that will group the rows?

Comment: For example, if I type the same customer name then other i.e. docket no., date, destination & weight will combine/merge in the same row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the script:

```
const HDR = 1 // header height
const GROUP_COL = 1 // in which column is the grouping value

function onEdit(e){      
  // we are interested only if value is not empty and the content of colum GROUP_COL has been changed
  if(!e.value || e.value===e.oldValue || e.range.columnStart!==GROUP_COL || e.range.rowStart<=HDR){
    return
  }

  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  const values = sh.getDataRange().getValues().slice(HDR-1)
  const existingRows = values.map((r,i)=>({ row:HDR+i, cells:r, found:r[GROUP_COL-1]==e.value })).filter(x=>x.found)
  console.log(existingRows)
  if(existingRows.length===0){
    return
  }

  const destRange = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,existingRows[0].cells.length)
  const destRow = destRange.getValues()[0]

  // merge content into the new row
  existingRows.forEach(er=>{
    er.cells.forEach((c,i)=>{
      if(i===GROUP_COL-1 || er.row===e.range.rowStart){
        return
      }
      destRow[i] = (destRow[i] + "\n" + er.cells[i]).trim()
    })
  })

  destRange.setValues([destRow])

  // delete extra rows
  existingRows.forEach((er,i)=>{
    if(er.row!==e.range.rowStart){
      sh.deleteRow(er.row-i)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Sir!! Thank you so much!! I was tired of finding solution over a bunch of websites and videos. Thank you. But I have a small problem when I type the same customer name and get merged in the same row without typing other values. Sir, I want to run the script when I fill all columns with values i.e. docket no., date, destination & weight.

Comment: either modify the script, or enter all the values first, and a customer name as the last value you enter for a row. The script is triggered only if you enter a non-empty value for customer name.
If needed, you can also delete the customer name and re-enter it, it will also trigger the script